# Finding a function

Tags: definite-integrals

I have the value of a function's integral and two points of this function. I'm searching for the function. Is it possible to find it?
$$\int F dx= a$$
$$F(b)= F(c)= d$$
$a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are known. I'm searching for $F$

Comment: i'm a mechanical engineer and i need it for an engineering stuff

Comment: ehh, it's a simple question, I've thrown my answer up.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the engineering application here?

Comment: ok, I'm new here and don't know about the notation, thank you.

Comment: i want set an application that gives the different dimensions used for the conception of a conveyor for bulk transporting, i'm organizing my calculation on microsoft excel, and i want to modelize the section of the bulk on the belt of the conveyor, for that i need the function of the extern generatrice of the bulk, and all i have is the area (ie the integral) and the two points (according to the standard of the belt conveyor)

Answer (score 0):

$$F = 0$$

Essentially what is being asked is:

$$\int0dx = a$$
Where $a$ is a constant. If $F > 0$ then there would be an $x$ in the solution somewhere.

Comment: yes i understand, i can't copy the boundaries here, we have boundaries in the integral, the integral is between two values, so F=!0.  i'm searching for the interpolation of this function, i don't know if it's possible or no, all what i have is the value of its integral and 2 points.

Comment: Better give me the values then mate, can't help you otherwise. The solution would be to differentiate the solution of the integral, which I have done, assuming a is constant, if it isn't then I need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution is not unique. Given any solution $f$ to
$$ \int_{y}^{z} F(x) \, dx = a, \\
F(b)=F(c)=d,
 $$
the function
$$ f(x) + x' (x'^2-b'^2)(x'^2-c'^2), $$
where $k'=k-(y+z)/2$, is also a solution (same values at $c,d$, and it is odd on the interval of integration, so has integral zero).

There is an easy way to find a solution, however. Let $f(x)=d+A(x-b)(x-c)$. Clearly this satisfies $f(b)=f(c)=d$. The integral is easy to give the correct value by choosing the right value of $A$:
$$ a = \int_y^z f(x) \, dx = d(y-z)+A\left( \frac{z^3-y^3}{3}-(b+c)\frac{z^2-y^2}{2}+bc(z-y) \right) \\
= (y-z)\left( d+A\left(bc -(b+c) \frac{y+z}{2} + \frac{z^2+zy+y^2}{3} \right)\right) $$
If that's zero, try multiplying by f another power of $x$.